# Preventing "Can't enter break mode at this time" error message?

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am copying a HTML table from a webpage, to excel. The data is being pasted in a temporary sheet added in the workbook. When pasting it on Excel, it is displaying the error message "Can't enter break mode at this time"", which is preventing me from moving further. I am getting this error when I am debugging the code, but when I am playing it, it is directly showing error code 91. I am looking for a word in the webpage, and trying to copy that table in Excel, but its copying the whole page on my temporary sheet, and throwing that error message. Please find below my code:

```
sub sample()

Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object
Dim Clipboard As Object
Dim Tabl_name As IHTMLElement

last_lin1st = Worksheets("sheet1").Columns(2).Find("Sum").Row
val_nci = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value

With ThisWorkbook
.Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "temp"
End With

Set ie = Nothing
Set IeDoc = Nothing
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
strHTML = "webURL"

ie.navigate strHTML

Set IeDoc = ie.document
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

msg = ie.document.Body.innerhtml

For x = 0 To tables.Length
If tables(x).innerText Like "*End Analysis*" Then
 Set Clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
clipboard.SetText tables(x).outerHTML
Clipboard.PutInClipboard

Worksheets("temp").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: why use the clipboard?  simply dig out the text into a string.

Comment: `val_nci = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value` what is the value of `i`? And what is that variable supposed to be for?

Comment: Actually this is just a snippet of my code. This I is being fetched from a For loop, which will vary.

Comment: clipboard is to copy that table on webpage, which I can copy on an excel sheet. Because I need some other details of the table, like date updated, and previous status. The motive is not to copy the string, but to verify the previous status and the date on that row, where the status is being displayed.

Comment: @user9710880 Are you sure you haven't accidentally set any breakpoints in the code?

Comment: @user9710880: oh ok, my bad.

Comment: @dwirony - how will I know if I have added any breakpoint? Is there any way to figure out if its added by mistake, because as far as I know, I haven't done that..

Comment: @user9710880 When you're looking at the code in the module, is there a red circle next to any of the lines? That would indicate a manual breakpoint.

Comment: @dwirony - no..I haven't added any breakpoint..I added it earlier while debugging, but then I removed it. Also, I am getting this error when I am debugging, but when I am running the code, its showng error code 91.

Comment: That's likely the cause of it - a run-time error would have the VBE enter break mode, and for some reason that error is happening while something else is going on and the VBE can't break at this time. Exactly what line/instruction is blowing up with error 91?

Comment: You seem to be using undeclared variables, is `Option Explicit` specified at the top of the module? If not, VBA will happily compile a typo, which can lead to this kind of bugs.

Comment: sorry to return to clipboard again, why do no need to create one every loop iteration?  I just think clipboard is suspect, I've worked on system that had concurrency issues and I had to write OS synchronisation code to stop excessive clipboard use.  So to me clipboards are suspect.  I appreciate it does a lot more for you; in this case it parses a table.  I'd still look to abolish the use of that code.

Comment: I'd bet $5 your problem goes away if you re-write the code to not use the clipboard. :)

Comment: where is `tables` defined?  I'd follow Matheiu's advice and add `Option Explicit`.

Comment: @S Meaden - If I don't add Clipboard, then how will I copy the text from the IE to my excel.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon- As soon as I am pasting the data in Excel, I am getting this error message.